# Weird for loop in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

I have a codewars problem and i'm new to python (less than 24hrs using it).
I'm solving the diamond problem:

> Task:
>
> You need to a string that when printed, displays a diamond shape on
>   the screen using asterisk ("*") characters. Please see provided test
>   cases for exact output format.
>
> The shape that will be returned from print method resembles a diamond,
>   where the number provided as input represents the number of *’s
>   printed on the middle line. The line above and below will be centered
>   and will have 2 less *’s than the middle line. This reduction by 2 *’s
>   for each line continues until a line with a single * is printed at the
>   top and bottom of the figure.
>
> Return null if input is even number or negative (as it is not possible
>   to print diamond with even number or negative number).
>
> Please see provided test case(s) for examples.
>
> Python Note
>
> Since print is a reserved word in Python, Python students must
>   implement the diamond(n) method instead, and return None for invalid
>   input.

My code:

```
def diamond(n):
    retorno = " *\n"
    if n%3 == 0:
        for i in range(n,0,-2):
            retorno += i * "*" 
            print(retorno + str(i));
    #return retorno
```

Test case:

```
expected =  " *\n"
expected += "***\n"
expected += " *\n"
test.assert_equals(diamond(3), expected)
```

The output:

```
 *
***3
 *
****1
```

How come the first "*" from the initialization of the var is repeating like it's inside the for loop?

Comment: are you sure you're not calling your method twice? and the first snippet is not returning anything. so your test cannot be true in any case.

Comment: I know the tests won't pass, but i'm wondering why the first "*" is repeating like it's inside the for loop, also, im using the online interpreter of codewars.com

Comment: BTW, your `diamond` function is not supposed to print any output. It's supposed to create a string and return it.

Comment: I'm just doing the print for debug purposes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, let me explain you what exactly is happening in your script step by step:

That is your code with the "number of line":

```
(1)def diamond(n):
(2)    retorno = " *\n"
(3)    if n%3 == 0:
(4)        for i in range(n,0,-2):
(5)            retorno += i * "*" 
(6)            print(retorno + str(i))
```

1. line 1, n = 3
2. line 2, n = 3, retorno = " *\n"
3. line 5, n = 3, i = 3, retorno = " *\n***"
4. line 6, n = 3, i = 3, retorno = " *\n***", you print " *\n***3"
5. line 5, n = 3, i = 1, retorno = " *\n****"
6. line 6, n = 3, i = 1, retorno = " *\n****", you print " *\n****1"

So finally you have print in two times:

```
 *
***3
 *
****1
```

Please also note that in Python you should not use ";" and that if you want to test if the input number is odd you should use `n%2 == 1`.

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
retorno = " *\n"
```

and append to it after first iteration(i = 3):

```
retorno = " *\n***" # printed
# *
#***
```

No newline was appended.
After second iteration (i = 1):

```
retorno = " *\n****" # printed  
# *  
#****
```

the 2 printed retornos is exactly what you see.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't repeating. It starts life as *\n, the first time through the loop you add '***' so it becomes *\n***, the next time, you add '*' so it becomes *\n****, thus the output:

```
*
***

*
****
```

Note also that n%3 is not the way to test for odd numbers, you want n%2==1.